# Uncaught ReferenceError: questions is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: questions is not defined error while using global variable in other function.

JavaScript Code :

```
$(function() {
    var dialog,total_que=0;
    var questions = { name:{}, type:{}, options:{}}

    function addQuestion() {
        var que = new Array();
        var option = new Array();
        var new_element_label;
        var new_element = "";
        var i=0;
        form_fields = form[0].elements.length;

        if(form_fields<=2){
            que['name'] = form[0].elements[0].value;
            que['type']  = form[0].elements[1].value;
        }
        else
        {
            que['name'] = form[0].elements[0].value;
            que['type']  = form[0].elements[1].value;
            for(i=0;i<(form_fields-3);i++){
                option[i] = form[0].elements[i+3].value;
            }
        }

        switch(que['type']){
        case 'text':
            var new_element = '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="'+que['name']+'">';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        new_element_label = '<label for="name">'+que['name']+'</label><br>';
        new_element_label += '<div for="text">';
        new_element += '</div>';
        $('#add_polling_form fieldset').append("<br>"+new_element_label+new_element);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        form[0].reset();
        questions['name'][total_que] = que['name'];
        questions['type'][total_que] = que['type'];
        questions['options'][total_que] = option;
        total_que++;
        console.log(questions);
    }

    console.log(questions);
    dialog = $("#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Add Question": addQuestion,
            Cancel: function() {
                $('#que_option_val').html('');
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
                form[0].reset();
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#que_option_val').html('');
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
            form[0].reset();
        }
    });
    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on("submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
        dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
});

function add_que_option(que_type){
    var que_type = que_type;
    switch(que_type){
    case 'text':
        $('#que_option_val').html('');
        break;
    default:
        $('#que_option_val').html('<input type="button" class="ui-button" value="Add More      Option" onclick="add_option();">')
        $('#que_option_val').append("<input type='text' placeholder='Option for Question'>");
    }
}
function add_option(){
    $('#que_option_val').append("<input type='text' placeholder='Option for Question'>");
}
function save_form(){
    console.log(questions);
}
```

When I call addQuestion() function, value is being inserted in options array. but when I call save_form() it's giving me error in console like this.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: questions is not defined 
 save_form 
 onclick
```

Comment: There is not any global variable defined in the posted code.

Comment: Declare `questions` variable outside `jquery` ready function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `questions` is local to the anonymous function that's inside the `$(...)` call at the top. `save_form()` is defined outside of that function, so none of those local variables are visible to it.

You should either move `save_form` inside `$(function() { ... }` or move the declaration of `questions` outside it.

Comment: Or just do `window.questions = ...` and save yourself some time :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 How would that exactly help?

Comment: It's just a different way to assign a global variable.

Comment: @Teemu - That would avoid declaring a new variable name in the `$(function(){})` scope, thus any `questions` references inside the scope would point to the global variable.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Moving the variable declaration outside of it is equivalent to that.

Comment: @Barmar - I know but what I was saying is changing `var ` to `window.` saves you some typing. Of course, the best way is to move the declaration outside of the current scope.

Comment: `var` is 3 characters, `window` is 6 characters. How does that save you typing? And if you move it outside the function, you don't need the `var` declaration, just assign the variable.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I have moved save_form() function and it's working.